# setting date and time in timestamp datatype using php

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, .post

I am sending data from html to PHP using jQuery post function but  date and time not inserting in my column i am confusing where is my mistake. 
my column data type is `timestamp`

this is my `jQuery` code

```
function conf_suspenduser(arg)
{

    var day = $('#day').val();
    var month = $('#month').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    if(day == "" || month=="")
    {

        console.log('pelase insert')

    }
    else
    {

        var user = {
        arg:arg,
        day:day,
        month:month,
        year:year
                };

    $.post('conf_suspenduser.php',user,function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    })


    }

}
```

here is my php code

```
<?php

require('lib/db.php');
$db = new database();
$conn = $db->connection();

    $user_id = $_REQUEST['arg'];
    $day = $_REQUEST['day'];
    $month = $_REQUEST['month'];
    $year = $_REQUEST['year'];
      $date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0,0,0,$year,$month,$day));
          $sql = "update user SET userActive = 2, updated = $date where userId = $user_id";
    $queryresult = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($queryresult === TRUE)
    {   
        echo 'updated..';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not updated..';
    }

?>
```

I am fetching date,day,year from html in select tags like Facebook doing
i.e

```
<select id="month"><option value="1">Jan</option></select>
<select id="day"><option value="1">Jan</option></select>
<select id="year"><option value="2015">2015</option></select>
```

Comment: is the values getting posted properly??

Comment: Is console giving you: updated?

Comment: Does the `updated..` message get output to the console?  Check the logs on the webserver - does it have a record of the post request? What was the response code? Were there any corresponding entries in the error log?

Comment: yes i am getting values in php properly my column updated type is timestamp please sove this issue :(

Comment: I also think `$date` should be between single quotes inside your query

Comment: everything going good its updating userActive column but its not updateing the date column i don't know why its happening..

Comment: Please put between single quotes, if that does not work check what the column format is and if the value of $date is the same format. Or just use DATE_NOW() or NOW() Instead (dont remember wich one) :)

Comment: how can i use DATE_NOW() in query..?

Comment: and i have to save date thats why i am doing effort..

Comment: Btw, is userActive saved correctly?

Comment: yes userActive saved correctly

Comment: Have tried single quotes?

Comment: yes i tryed but its always giving me 2016-02-01 03-06-14 why its always giving me this date

Answer (score 0):

I think i see your issue:

Wrong:

`date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $year, $month, $day));`

Correct:

`date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));`

With all parameter:

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year));`

Info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Check the link i provided :)